# What is the recommended way to define a GUID for a driver?

Tags: c++, c, windows-ce

I would like to define/generate a GUID (interface class) for my test driver. What is the best way to do that 'programatically using C/C++' so it won't conflict with other devices/drivers in the system?

Also, are there any standard guidelines to follow or other things to keep in mind while creating a new GUID?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoCreateGuid is the Win32 API that does this using randomness sources including your network adapter.

Martyn

Answer (score 3):

Use a GUID generator. There is one bundled with Visual Studio. In 2008, it's under Tools > Create GUID.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there a way to create one programatically?

Comment: Sure. There's a GUID class somewhere in .NET if you're using that, and I'm sure you can find other GUID-generating algorithms on google. I would imagine there's plain Win32 calls you could make as well...

Comment: I would like to do that in C/C++. I am hoping to generate it on the fly, during the run-time when I plan to execute my test.

Comment: @MemoryLeak: you're not supposed to do that. I'm fairly certain that your driver would fail WinQual if you do.

Comment: @MSalters: Thanks. I am not sure if WinQual process is relevant here since this is for my own test purpose. Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: I might be misreading you, but as I understand it: You want to generate a GUID when you install your driver, to make testing easier. That's not the correct solution. Generate a GUID once, for your driver, and use versioning to differentiate different versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Boost, check out [Boost UUID (Universally Unique Id)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#Introduction) library.